# Ajax form loading incorrectly

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created a form using the code from [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples), which you can find in '.../examples/ajax_example/autotextfields'. In the example when you select both 'Ask me my first name' and ' Ask me my last name ' very fast, it is generating only one textfield. To achieve this bug, in this example you need to select very very fast, but I have bigger form and on select it is loading longer... This is very confusing for users and big problem for my project. Have you suggestions how to fix that? The bug is the same as in example module, so here is the code from example:

```
/**
 * Show/hide textfields based on AJAX-enabled checkbox clicks.
 */
function ajax_example_autotextfields($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['ask_first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Ask me my first name'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_autotextfields_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'textfields',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );
  $form['ask_last_name'] = array(
   '#type' => 'checkbox',
   '#title' => t('Ask me my last name'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_autotextfields_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'textfields',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  $form['textfields'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Generated text fields for first and last name"),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="textfields">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('This is where we put automatically generated textfields'),
  );

  // Since checkboxes return TRUE or FALSE, we have to check that
  // $form_state has been filled as well as what it contains.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['ask_first_name']) && $form_state['values']['ask_first_name']) {
    $form['textfields']['first_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('First Name'),
      '#required' => true,
    );
  }
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['ask_last_name']) && $form_state['values']['ask_last_name']) {
    $form['textfields']['last_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Last Name'),
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Me'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Selects the piece of the form we want to use as replacement text and returns
 * it as a form (renderable array).
 *
 * @return renderable array (the textfields element)
 */
function ajax_example_autotextfields_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['textfields'];

}
```

Comment: i am not very expert in ajax but i think so u have to disable ' Ask me my last name ' field when the first name field is ajax processing and when first field is done enable second again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code author wrote, for which he wants to write better code, or he wants to understand why it doesn't work, but without that code included. Please see [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for further explanation.

Comment: Mołot, I copied and pasted the code from example module and modified it, but the bug is the same as in example module, so I edited my question with the code.

Comment: Human love, do you have an idea how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Human love, you saved my day, I followed your instructions and now it is working!